# Replacing entire word/number in a line with SED with only partial match

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Can someone please tell me how I can replace a entire string with only partial? 
For Example if the txt file contains:

```
The number of water molecues: h20=20e43
```

And I need it to say:

```
The number of water molecues: h20=10e54
```

What I have so far is `sed 's/h20/h20=10e54/'`, which outputs:

```
The number of water molecues: h20=10e54=20e43
```

The problem is that the original value I want to replace is not always the same so I need it to search for the patter `h20=` only and replace the whole thing.

Comment: Will `sed 's/h20=.*/h20=20e43/` work ?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `s/\(h20=\)[[:alnum:]]*/\110e54/`

matches "h20=" (and remembers the value) followed by some alphanumeric chars; replaces with the remembered value (`\1`) plus the literal string you want.

Also: `perl -pe 's/h20=\K\w+/10e54/'`

Answer (score 0):

following your own idea, here is the fix.

```
echo "The number of water molecues: h20=10e54" |sed 's/h20=.*/h20=10e54/'
```

Comment: Oh, cnicutar has provided the same way 4 hours ago. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can also be used:

```
echo "The number of water molecues: h20=20e43" | awk '{sub(/h20=.*/,"h20=10e54")}1'
The number of water molecues: h20=10e54
```